# How do i update the video driver?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-2

How do I update the video driver for my Droid 2 Global? I have a custom Cyanogenmod installed but YouTube videos have a green bar, green tint, or are garbled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By installing a different version of Cyanogenmod. Android is not like Windows, where you have to install each driver separately: all the drivers come integrated in the ROM. Sometimes, with third-party ROMs like Cyanogenmod, they don't quite manage to integrate the drivers properly (because only the manufacturer has all the required information), so you get defects like this one.

If you found the problem in a stable release, release candidate, or beta of Cyanogenmod, you should report it to the maintainers for your phone so they can fix it. If you've been using a nightly snapshot, don't bother, as they are expected to have serious errors and aren't suitable for everyday use.

Upgrade to a newer release if there is one, or perhaps to an older release.

Comment: Thanks, but the latest official version for my phone is 7.2, which does not work at all. I'm using an unofficial version 9, http://rootzwiki.com/topic/17976-cyanogenmod-9-unofficial-for-droid-2-global-ics403-update-31512/page-153#entry1117799, Android 4.0.4. I don't think I will have any luck with an update. Why don't I have control? I bought an Android so I would have control over it unlike Apple!

Comment: Can I get the video driver out of an OEM ROM and copy it to this ROM?

Comment: In theory, yes, but it's not just a question of copying a file into the ROM. You need to do some programming to integrate the driver with the ROM, and then compile a new ROM from source. You might also need to replace other parts of the ROM (such as the kernel) with different versions compatible with the ROM. The maintainers of an unofficial ROM for the phone might be able to help you out, but if they could fix it they'd do it themselves. It's at least a few days' work even if you know what you're doing.

Comment: The fact we're here talking about installing a new OS on your phone shows how much control you have. Getting a driver working isn't hard because the phone's actively trying to stop you, like an iPhone does: it's hard because making and integrating OSes takes skill and work. The problem you're seeing now is probably with the integration, not the driver itself.

Answer (score 0):

I fond a "patch" solution. Basically, you must "downgrade" the video quality. To do the "downgrade" on Google's official app, follow these instructions:

1. Open a video with the YouTube app.
2. Tap any place of screen to show the menu (in landscape).
3. Hit the 3 dots on the top right corner.
4. Hit the settings icon to show the available resolutions of current video.
5. Select 240 or less.